# Existence of Hamming code

Tags: coding-theory

We are given a  number $n \geq 3$ and we know that the Hamming bound is satisfied. Does this imply that there is a Hamming code with length $\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}$, dimension $\frac{q^r-1}{q-1}-r$ and Hamming-distance $3$ or do we have to construct such a code, given that the bound is satisfied?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hamming bound is an upper bound on the size of codes. It's not a tight bound in general, though in some specific cases it is achievable. Codes achieving the Hamming bound are called [perfect codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound#Perfect_codes).

When the alphabet size is a prime power, all perfect codes are known: apart from some trivial cases (repetition codes, codes with one codeword, and codes containing all possible codewords), they share the same parameters as a [Hamming code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) or a [Golay code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golay_code).

What this means is that if your alphabet size is a prime power and you have parameters satisfying the Hamming bound, then a code with these parameters actually exists only in the cases listed above. In any other case, the bound isn't tight.